# Is it possible to reload the webview if the page is not completely loaded?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I would like to know if there is a way to detect if the page is loaded completely in a webview - and if not loaded completely, automatically reload it again until the page is loaded entirely.

Is there a way to detect it ?

Thank you.

Comment: All you need is the WebViewClient. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html  override some of the functions there ie. the onPageFinished()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no definitive way to tell if the page will not finish loading. Still you can achieve similar kind of functionality by implementing WebViewClient.

```
Timer t= new Timer("pageloadtimer", true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    t.cancel();
  }
}
public void loadURL(String url, long timeout){
  t.schedule(new TimerTask(){
    public void run(){
      webview.reload();
    }
  }, timeout);
  webview.load(url);
}
```

Comment: How did you make this work? `webview.reload()` fails with: `java.lang.Throwable:` A WebView method was called on thread 'pageloadtimer'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

prateek i think this will work for u.......

in your webview set webview client as follows....

```
wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

});
```

and use webViewclients different callback methods to detect page loade or not or did u recieve some error while loading etc......

some of its methods are

```
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,Bitmap favicon) {}

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {}

public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {}

public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {};
```

look for these methods.....

Thanks.